# Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter, Swift

Tags: swift, timer, closures

I have been working on a count down timer and it was going ok, but when i decided to restructure the code in MVC and moved part of the code i got this error
(Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter).
i tried changing the struct to a class but then the timer stoped working and wouldn't update the label. any solution for either issue would help.

```
struct CountDownLogic {

    var hours: Int = 0
    var mins: Int = 0
    var secs: Int = 0
    
   .
   .
   .

    mutating func startTimer() {
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { Timer in

            if self.secs > 0 {
                    self.secs = self.secs - 1

                } else if self.mins > 0 {
                    self.mins = self.mins - 1
                    self.secs = 59
                } else if self.hours > 0 {
                    self.hours = self.hours - 1
                    self.mins = 59
                    self.secs = 59
                }

                self.updateLabel()
            }
    }
    
    mutating func updateLabel() {
        dateSet = "\(hours):\(mins):\(secs)"

    }

}
```

any help is much appreciated ..

Comment: This really needs to be a class... If you want to keep it as a struct I suggest setting a block as a var that gets called when the timer updates.

Comment: i changed it to a class but the timer is not working nor is it updating the label! any idea on how to trigger it ?

Comment: MVC uses call backs a lot. like var updateHandler: (_ hours: Int, _ minutes: Int, _ seconds: Int) -> Void and then assign a block to handle changes.

Comment: Or being a class is passed by reference you can do key value observing or just a block to signify values have changed

Comment: Note that this approach is wrong. Don't assume you will be called precisely when you think you will. You can lose time this way (particularly if the app ever goes into the background). Create a timer that tells your UI to update every second. The UI then should compute endTime-currentTime and displays the formatted value. This will also get rid of your timer management issues.